# Convert mysql query into query builder

Tags: laravel, query-builder

Hello Guys I am new with the query builder of laravel.
I want to convert this query into laravel query builder. Thank you in advance.

```
$bo_facilities = ' SELECT 
a.bo_facility_code,
a.bo_facility_groupcode,
a.bo_number,
a.bo_indYesOrNo,
a.bo_indLogic,
b.bo_content_facility_description

FROM 

bo_facilities AS a 

RIGHT JOIN bo_content_facilities AS b
ON b.bo_content_facility_code = a.bo_facility_code AND b.bo_content_facility_facilityGroupCode = a.bo_facility_groupcode
WHERE a.bo_hotel_code =  "1" GROUP BY b.bo_content_facility_description';
```

My groupBy method didnt work..

```
$join->groupBy('b.bo_content_facility_description');
```

this is my whole code
I didn't know the best way.

```
DB::table('bo_facilities AS a')
->select("a.bo_facility_code", "a.bo_facility_groupcode", "a.bo_number", "a.bo_indYesOrNo", "a.bo_indLogic", "b.bo_content_facility_description")
->join('bo_content_facilities AS b', function ($join) { 
    $join->on('b.bo_content_facility_code', '=', 'a.bo_facility_code'); 
    $join->on('b.bo_content_facility_facilityGroupCode', '=', 'a.bo_facility_groupcode');
    $join->groupBy('b.bo_content_facility_description');
    })
->where('a.bo_hotel_code', $hotelCode)
->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I already fixed my problem.

```
$bo_facilities_raw = DB::table('bo_facilities AS a')
->join('bo_content_facilities AS b', function ($join) {
    $join->on([['b.bo_content_facility_code', '=', 'a.bo_facility_code'], ['b.bo_content_facility_facilityGroupCode', '=', 'a.bo_facility_groupcode']]); 
    })
->select("a.bo_hotel_code","a.bo_facility_code", "a.bo_facility_groupcode", "a.bo_number", "a.bo_indYesOrNo", "a.bo_indLogic", "b.bo_content_facility_description", "b.bo_content_facility_code", "b.bo_content_facility_facilityGroupCode")
->where('a.bo_hotel_code', 1)
->get();

$bo_facilities_decode = json_decode($bo_facilities_raw, true);

$remove_dupli = array_unique(array_column($bo_facilities_decode, 'bo_content_facility_description'));

$bo_facilities = array_intersect_key($bo_facilities_decode, $remove_dupli);
```

the duplication of records was inside the multidimensional array thats why i use array unique and array intersect key for removing the duplicate descriptions.